# Transistor cascading

Tags: transistors

[image]

Why in this circuit transistor Q2 is opened only by 50%?

Comment: Can you [edit] to explain why you think it's open 50%? Do you mean 50% voltage or 50% time?

Comment: What did you expect? 80%?

Comment: Perhaps the AC input is 50% positive and 50% negative?

Answer (score 1):

It is because the voltage divider gives the base a voltage of less then 1.4V, it gives him 0.24 volts not enough for the darlington configuration to conduct full time. 50% is about correct, it is an AC signal and you are measuring DC. The output would be on just under 50% of the time. Depending on the transistors the output Q2 starts conducting when the input rises above about 1.4 volts, that is where it would start to conduct. Good luck with this.

Comment: I disagree. the duty cycle with 5Vp sine 50 Hz will be about 80% off due to the difference in input impedance for Off and On of Vbe, and the cap impedance at 50 Hz. So that the VBe junctions act as a partial positive clamp at 1.4V making the average current more off than on by 60% and an average Vdc of - 2.5V with a clamped +ve peak of 1.4V. This means the cap drops 8.6V asymmetrically due to the impedance divider being partially non-linear.